# typescript merges arguments of enum function type

Tags: typescript

I believe I came across a funny behavior of typescript type system. I have a work case where I have 2 hashmaps, one for arrays of items, another one of functions that work with the same type. Both hashmaps have the same keys for the same type. When extracting them statically ie inlining the key name it works as expected. But when I try to iterate over the keys typescript starts to merge function arguments in the second hashmap. Please see the provided links.

I am aware that I can write a switch case or imperative if statements to refine the type for the key but in reality there are many more keys than in the example and I would like to get where I need to improve my types or get typescript to infer the types correctly.

[Full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwChRIoAhBZKAzAge1YBsJUtyrxoAYQYoAxpgDOwYgEssAcz78aAERmjgIilCgByVLswwA2gF0A3Nr0FDdM5Z27RtwfYqVlQgBYRRAawktHQwoAApUYnkjAEoEAD4oADdWGQATByZMcMjMWlj4BOS0jPEwiKioQXzClPT3CgpU3w4I6ESIqFT1YEw1DUsm0RbiNo7RH38JTEEJgMtPKABpCBBAxD8V1gAzKD7gS1FWLCkoDdXMZdWzBmN9XQAaawe9ZwsGrZwsDRkjqHkIYAzXx+AA8iygEAAHsAIFhUoFLhI4qEzhdYkgrCNgDhiLxxsCJMYzm8PB8vsAfrx-sAAJIwvASMEQ6Gw+FLFZIlErNHITEAnG8LoaIkrEkNAD0ACpJdpJVBAKDk2FYMKgh2IIw0UGoEECW1YpDYwC8UAABvj-DATWg4aaZPSJJaoLLxRRDsdNOa-HBENSgf5Qndogcjic7RAGd6-gC6eGJAGDEGKGGIwA6PXEACiqHGoWT3oSGJ0npgufpMETZETFClMqgcsAMuRyNUazTaqDp02eq0Adx8vDtUBkgVEqA4XFSzooZO+v3aHDSqBhAAUWnIuSALhz0VY3aH7QxqTGGevojuQx7ZgeAX6-CeSrN5jo20eACoCBh7Yza7anUXGAAMpgNDoyYSGm+pZjmVg6KW4aYK+AjVLyOgoVANbQahcodhIrB4NAIyoDhvC9rCqqjuOnazFabZ4ZEOpoJE+CwsAgQ-ka0DThSvzahhKGSi6qFFrMsF4KeqFkPcVinh46F1lAjZfPqLZau+HZmlRUAkf2mhDmRY4QBOdYupxlJJKOC4wgA4kyUIwnCCIcsiqJLNuRbnoO+4+tG9onme7qqpeXmAsJZyJkJwKPipNAITQiCfospgAUBVigeBmbZl4oQYSJ8H0m+kBIYWgmyYJcnsVAEioHhUBeKgYCQMcml9mZ86pIu0C6d2sjAHZml2saqBRlgJDqLxOj8WNnoiWJKESVJ7hAA)

[Small example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwChRIoAhBZKAzAge1YBsJUtyrxoAYQYoAxpgDOwYgEssAcz78aAMTiIAFKmLzMMAJQIAfFABurGQBMA3Mugr6m7brqH4J81dvV7wpzsxBNw8LGwoKADMcLFFgGVZeAGsIRI0omMw1KAAfKAccvKDMT0tkCigoAHpKqEBQcihRVmJiCFioH3KodNFbCuqoQBlyKDlG5tbgdoFO7o0kDCgARjJ9CjIgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fishy part is that when you have `forEach` on an array with type `A[] | B[] | C[]`, the item type [implicitly becomes `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwChRIoAhBZKAzAge1YBsJUtyrxoAYQYoAxpgDOwYgEssAcz4UAJhFEdUxaKNZYpUGcAh4JmGAG0AulAA+dK7aiCrFCoeMSAdADNWxAKKoogAWABTueAgAfIwA9LEGeGAcMqKGaFggrmQAlEA) because [it doesn't know what to do](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34605).

So let's fix that like this...

```js
function validate<K extends Keys>(key: K) {
  type Item = Dict[K][number];
  const items = getItems(key) as Item[];
  const check = getCheck(key) as (arg: Item) => void;

  items.forEach(
    (item) => { // no implicit any
      check(item)
    },
  )
}
```

[Tada](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwChRIoAhBZKAzAge1YBsJUtyrxoAYQYoAxpgDOwYgEssAcz78aAERmjgIilCgByVLswwA2gF0A3Nr0FDdM5Z27RtwfYqVlQgBYRRAawktHQwoAApUYnkjAEoEAD4oADdWGQATByZMcMjMWlj4BOS0jPEwiKioQXzClPT3CgpU3w4I6ESIqFT1YEw1DUsm0RbiNo7RH38JTEEJgMtPKABpCBBAxD8V1gAzKD7gS1FWLCkoDdXMZdWzBmN9XQAaawe9ZwsGrZwsDRkjqHkIYAzXx+AA8iygEAAHsAIFhUoFLhI4qEzhdYkgrCNgDhiLxxsCJMYzm8PB8vsAfrx-sAAJIwvASMEQ6Gw+FLFZIlErNHITEAnG8LoaIkrEkNAD0ACpJdpJVBAKDk2FYMKgh2IIw0UGoEECW1YpDYwC8UAABvj-DATWg4aaZPSJJaoLLxRRDsdNOa-HBENSgf5Qndogcjic7RAGd6-gC6eGJAGDEGKGGIwA6PXEACiqHGoWT3oSGJ0npgufpMETZETFDJ31+7Q4aVQMKZUJhcIRHORqKW6Ks2qgMbwDD2xkWpmMuEIJDeRZDmmTayjtPtXJAsVQgUHbln7tVswYvtmq-XgWyFUH1SStRKs3mOgXaf1WZzVh0pfDl5Q4vFSqgMjwYANqIdrWiAr46HuwLvng0TgWQ9xWLBZBAA)

Answer (score 3):

Well, as is almost always the case, the compiler is right, but not in an obvious way.

I looked only at the "small example", I'm copying it here and commenting on it:

```js
type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: boolean }
type C = { c: string }

type FA = (arg: A) => void;
type FB = (arg: B) => void;
type FC = (arg: C) => void;
```

Now, let's call `FUnion` the subject of your question:

```
type FUnion= FA | FB | FC;
```

`FUnion` is either:

- a function that takes A OR
- a function that takes B OR
- a function that takes C

TypeScript is smart enough to understand that, whatever the case, FComposed is still a function, so you can call it. But what should you pass to it in order to have it work?

If I give you an `FUnion`, you don't know if it requires either an A, B or C.
Imagine you call it with an `A`, and the underlying function is an `FB`: you would get (hopefully) a runtime error when it tries to access property `b`.

So, TypeScript requires, in order to call an `FUnion` you must honor *every* possible contract, so you must provide something that is an A, a B and C:

```
type U = A & B & C;

// FUnion is equivalent to
type FUnion = (arg: A & B & C) => void;
```

I'm no TypeScript expert of Haskell guru. I suspect there is some algebraic wizardry under this equivalence, but I hope this example clears up the mistery.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am aware of this behavior with `FA & FB &FC`, the small example is to illustrate the possible but that I have in the full example. There typescript should be smart enough to infer the type of the function to call with with a specific type. However instead it takes a union of all possible functions and merges their arguments. In the small example I tried to highlight this behavior. My main question is regardless inferring or refine the type for the function since TS is able to infer the type of argument correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, just saw the notification of acceptance and upvote and I revisited this, actually the root of the problem is `Array.prototype.forEach` has item as generic and not the array itself, hence TypeScript has to eagerly infer the item type. We can solve that by using something like...

```js
const forEach = <T extends any[]>(xs: T, fn: (x: T[number], i: number, xs: T) => void) =>
  xs.forEach(fn as any)

// "T" is the array, whereas in `Array.prototype.forEach` "T" is the item
```

Also we'll need generics all the way down so we need to stop eager inference in `getCheck` also...

```js
function getCheck<K extends Keys>(key: K) {
  return checks[key] as (item: Dict[K][number]) => void;
}
```

Typescript isn't sure that `Checks[K]` can take `Dict[K][number]` as an argument because of the involvement on the generic `K`. Think of it as both `K` could be different hence we explicitly type `checks[key]`.

Now you're good to go

```js
function validate<K extends Keys>(key: K) {
  const items = getItems(key); // no type needed
  const check = getCheck(key); // no type needed

  check;

  forEach(
    items,
    (item) => {
      check(item)
    },
  )
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwChRIoAhBZKAzAge1YBsJUtyrxoAYQYoAxpgDOwYgEssAcz78aAERmjgIilCgByVLswwA2gF0A3Nr0FDdM5Z27RtwfYqVlQgBYRRAawktHQwoAApUYnkjAEoEAD4oADdWGQATByZMcMjMWlj4BOS0jPEwiKioQXzClPT3CgpU3w4I6ESIqFT1YEw1DUsm0RbiNo7RH38JTEEJgMtPKABpCBBAxD8V1gAzKD7gS1FWLCkoDdXMZdWzBmN9XQAaawe9ZwsGrZwsDRkjqHkIYAzXx+AA8iygEAAHsAIFhUoFLhI4qEzhdYkgrCNgDhiLxxsCJMYzqY0IFQjIYXhet1jItTMZcIQSKZqklapYPB8vsAfrx-sAAJKUiRgiHQ2HwpYrJEolZo5CYgE43hdDRElZvDyHY6afH+OCIflA-yhO7RA5HE4UiB4CQGv4AoU2iSmgzmijW20wAB0W1YxAAoqhxuTKQaEhidHq-DBQzaYO6yO6KNqTn7A8GvAwQQAVMUwuGBHggMzIyFTKA5x5bLBZSGYHMM-BEYimR4yTCMluPcsN1lFVLVKzl33+oMhmuktBYEDRd6fb6-docNKoGGiqEFyWI5GopboqypzSetYOwXC2Wz8xQAD0N+wrCg1GgWAgECaqUPlt1swYRtml7mre95YI+z7YG+H5WIeszzDo6bjl4oRWDoJ73ChYSeqykY6Lh0Zxngc64eQ6E6HOZBAA)

I like this solution slightly more than previous because I don't have to retype `items` and `check`.